# The smart way of set custom validations message in laravel without making a request class

Tags: php, laravel

> I found difficulties to set custom validation message without making a
>   request class. That's why I am explaining it for a better
>   understanding.

**Default validation of laravel:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories',
        ]);
        $input = $request->all();
        Category::create($input);

        Session::flash('create_category','Category created successfully');
        return redirect('admin/categories');
    }
```

It will show the default message of laravel. In this question-answer section I will show how easily I solved this problem with the help of laravel documentation.
you can find other ways of doing this here in [laravel documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to simply pass the three values to the `validate` parameter.

- Your input as `$request`
- Your rules as `$rules`
- Your custom message as `$message`

---

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = ['name'=>'required|unique:categories'];
    $message = [
        'name.required' => 'The category name is required',
        'name.unique'   => 'Category name should be unique'
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules, $message);

    $input = $request->all();
    Category::create($input);

    Session::flash('create_category','Category created successfully');
    return redirect('admin/categories');
}
```

**I found that this is the smartest way of doing custom validation without making a request class. If your input field is a few and you want to your validation in the controller then you can do your validation in this way.**

---

Thank's for reading.